# How do I loop through a file, byte by byte, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, blob, filereader

I need some help getting my head around how the file is accessed in JavaScript to do some operations on it.

I would like to loop through a file byte by byte using JavaScript.
I can already select which file I would like to read. And I can read preset byte of the file.

I've found this nice example on how to read a slice of a file here:

> http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Here is the snippet of code which I'm playing with:

```
<style>
  #byte_content {
    margin: 5px 0;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  #byte_range { margin-top: 5px; }
</style>

<input type="file" id="files" name="file" /> Read bytes: 
<span class="readBytesButtons">
  <button data-startbyte="0" data-endbyte="4">1-5</button>
  <button data-startbyte="5" data-endbyte="14">6-15</button>
  <button data-startbyte="6" data-endbyte="7">7-8</button>
  <button>entire file</button>
</span>
<div id="byte_range"></div>
<div id="byte_content"></div>

<script>
  function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {

    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
    if (!files.length) {
      alert('Please select a file!');
      return;
    }

    var file = files[0];
    var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
    var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
      if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = evt.target.result;
        document.getElementById('byte_range').textContent = 
            ['Read bytes: ', start + 1, ' - ', stop + 1,
             ' of ', file.size, ' byte file'].join('');
      }
    };

    var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
  }

  document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
      var startByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-startbyte');
      var endByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-endbyte');
      readBlob(startByte, endByte);
    }
  }, false);
</script>
```

Now I would like to loop through the file, four bytes at a time, but cannot seem to figure out how to do that. The reader does not seem to allow me to read more than once.

Once I can read from the file more than once, I should be able to iterate through it quite easily with something like this:

```
while( placemark != fileSize-4 ){
    output = file.slice(placemark, placemark + 4);      
    console.log(output);
    placemark = placemark + 5;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!
Here is a link to a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FredWFourie/m0Lt9sye/) and [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bL0ugSSDozbF8iMbHC9n?p=info) version

Comment: If you can, I would try and refactor out your DOM manipulation code from your file reading code. This way if you have a clear separation of concerns it will be easier to debug and make changes to.

Comment: I agree! I feel that once that's done, the rest should be easy... But, I'm not sure how?

Comment: put it into a plnkr then I'll have a look at refactoring it, then solving it

Comment: Okay... added fiddling options.

Comment: If I could get around the "already busy reading Blobs" issue, I'm guessing that could also help?

Comment: first of all in the plnkr version, you function doesn't have a closely brace

Comment: Yeah, that could be. I slapped everything together hastily. I don't really know plnkr, but the jsFiddle works fine

Comment: Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BHQ9HGOW8QTHy3bogiHN?p=preview), I refactored it a tiny bit. I changed the way you refer to the bytes, they are indexed at 0, so you should talk about the byte at position 1 to be byte 0. it gets less confusing. I'm not sure what isn't working, I uploaded a file and it showed the contents and that.

Comment: The code was working fine. I was reading from byte '1' because the first byte in my test file needed to be skipped. I posted that because, that was the example code with which I was working with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm  not sure it is what you wanted but maybe it can help, and anyway I had fun.
I tried setting `reader` and `file` vars as global :

```js
var reader = new FileReader(), step = 4, stop = step, start = 0, file;

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', load, true);

function load() {
  var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
  file = files[0];
  reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
      var result = evt.target.result;
      document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent += result; 
      document.getElementById('byte_range').textContent = ['Read bytes: ', start, ' - ', start+result.length,
        ' of ', file.size, ' byte file'
      ].join('');
    }
  }
}

function next() {
  if (!file) {
    alert('Please select a file!');
    return;
  }
  var blob = file.slice(start, stop);
  reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);

  start+= step;
  stop = start+step;
}

function loop() {
  if (!file) {
    alert('Please select a file!');
    return;
  }
  if (start < file.size) {
    next();
    setTimeout(loop, 50);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="file" />Read bytes:
<span class="readBytesButtons">
  <button onclick="next()">next</button>
  <button onclick="loop()">loop</button>
</span>
<div id="byte_range"></div>
<div id="byte_content"></div>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Yes. That works great, thank you. I guess it makes sense that those vars global.

Answer (score 1):

I'd read the blob as an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) and use a [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) to read through the data

```js
  function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {

    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
    if (!files.length) {
      alert('Please select a file!');
      return;
    }

    var file = files[0];
    var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
    var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(evt) {
        var placemark = 0, dv = new DataView(this.result), limit = dv.byteLength - 4, output;
        while( placemark <= limit ){
            output = dv.getUint32(placemark);      
            console.log(' 0x'+("00000000" + output.toString(16)).slice(-8));
            placemark += 4;
        }     
    };

    var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" onchange="readBlob(0, 100)">
```

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely also an answer.

Answer (score -2):

In the onload handler of FileReader, convert the result to string (`toString()`), then read 4 chars at a time with the string's `slice` method.

```
var contents = null;

reader.onload = function(){
    contents = reader.result.toString();
}

var startByte = 0;

// read 4 bytes at a time
var step = 4;

// actual reading (doesn't alter the contents object)
console.log(contents.slice(startByte, step))

// update the next startByte position
startByte += step;
```

Comment: 4 bytes != 4 characters

Comment: Yeah, that would be a cute little solution, if I didn't need the actual bytes- Like @Justinas mentioned. Thank you both, though.